# Fixing the deprecated issue with Sequelize and nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

[image]

Can someone tell me what I need to do to fix the deprecated issue displayed in the image below? What do I need to do for this?

```
    var Sequelize = require("sequelize");

    var connection = new Sequelize('databaseschemaname','nodejs','replacewithpassword', {host: 'localhost', dialect: 'mysql'
 operatorsAliases: false,
});

    const Op = Sequelize.Op;

    var Article = connection.define('article', {
      title: Sequelize.STRING,
      body: Sequelize.TEXT
    });


    connection.sync().then(function () {
      Article.findAll().then(function(articles) {
        console.log(articles.length);
      })
    });
```

Comment: Are you issuing any other query before the `CREATE TABLE...` one? Based on the [Sequelizejs documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators) referenced in the image, it looks like it's referring to operators you would use on a `SELECT` or `UPDATE` - like `AND`, `OR`, `LIKE` etc.

Comment: No, when I ran node app (for node app.js) that picture was of all of the results at the time. The code is still working but since it said deprecated I wanted to make sure I was aware of why and what to do to fix it.  I don't want to be doing something the wrong way. So you understand this is just simple starter code not much in it currently.  Just getting started on the Sequalize and checking out how it works.  I may need a different one for my oracle database as well.

Comment: Can you post the actual error message as text instead of an image? Will make it easier for people to find this question.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46608382/sequelize-deprecated-error-message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find more info at this link:

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html

Then scroll down to "Operators security".

There are a few ways to deal with this issue. If you just want to get rid of the message, basically you can add the following to your connection: `{ operatorsAliases: false }`

I don't know what your connection query looks like, but it could look something like this:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const connection = new Sequelize(db, user, pass, { 
    operatorsAliases: false 
});
```

Comment: Yes,  I am getting closer to figuring this out.  I have seen the http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators-security     However I don't want operatorsAliases: false I want to follow the security and not have to stop checking them. I will post the code now that I understand better what might be the issue.